# Many download tasks

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsurlsession

I'm building an iOS app that will download 300 pdf files each one with more or less 3mb in size.

I came across a really nice tutorial with a code example: [Link](http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/)
Code example: [LINK](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/BGTransferDemo.zip)

The problem is that the app will freeze for some time, when running this code to add all the 300 tasks:

```
-(void)startAllDownloads{

    for (int i=0; i<[self.arrFileDownloadData count]; i++) {
        FileDownloadInfo *fdi = [self.arrFileDownloadData objectAtIndex:i];


        // Check if a file is already being downloaded or not.

        if (!fdi.isDownloading) {

            // Check if should create a new download task using a URL, or using resume data.
            if (fdi.taskIdentifier == -1) {
                //new NSURLSessionDownloadTask
                fdi.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:fdi.downloadSource]];
            }
            else{

                fdi.downloadTask = [self.session downloadTaskWithResumeData:fdi.taskResumeData];

            }

            // Keep the new taskIdentifier.
            fdi.taskIdentifier = fdi.downloadTask.taskIdentifier;

            NSLog(@"starting download id:%lu",fdi.taskIdentifier);

            // Start the download.
            //dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [fdi.downloadTask resume];
            //});

            // Indicate for each file that is being downloaded.
            fdi.isDownloading = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with a dispatch_queue but with no success, It always freezes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, if the app freeze that means you are running long tasks on main thread. Second if you used the dispatch that you commented, it's the wrong one, the right one is `dispatch_get_global_queue` instead of `dispatch_get_main_queue()`

Comment: Yes, I know, the problem is that I'm not very familiar with Grand Central Dispatch.

Comment: Have you used `NSURLSessionConfiguration` ?

Comment: Yes, NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfiguration:identifier];
            sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 5;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it in this way:

```
#define __ASYNC_BLOCK(code)         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), code)
#define __UI_THREAD_TASK(code)      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), code);
```

and then somewhere in your code you can use like this:

```
...

__ASYNC_BLOCK(^{

// do download...

    __UI_THREAD_TASK(^{
        // update ui
    })
});

...
```

EDIT: Look at **Tracking Progress** section [Background Transfer Service in iOS 7 SDK](http://www.appcoda.com/background-transfer-service-ios7/).

> Next, because the download task works in background threads, any visual upgrades must take place in the main thread of the app. So, inside the block of the addOperationWithBlock: method of the main queue operation

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following:

You'll use grand dispatch and set the priority to high. That will allow you to run the app while the stuff is downloaded in the background.

In you `viewDidLoad` method add the following line of code

```
{dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{ //1

               // DO ALL YOUR CODING HERE 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 2






    });

           //3

    });
```

And the explanation

1 we set a background task. In your case to download the pdf files asynchronously.
 2 we do something on the main queue, like for example update the UI to display the PDFs after they   have downloaded. 
3 We close the brackets and the whole method

Hope that helped. Regards!

EDIT: THAT"S A WAY TO DOWNLOAD PDF'S

```
// Get the PDF Data from the url in a NSData Object
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[
    NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com/info.pdf"]];

// Store the Data locally as PDF File
NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[
    [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]
        stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"
]];

NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath 
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myPDF.pdf"];
[pdfData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


// Now create Request for the file that was saved in your documents folder
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[webView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[webView setDelegate:self];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not help, in the ViewDidLoad I only create the a NSURLSession, them I create several objects each one is a NSURLSessionDownloadTask, the creation of many consecutive NSURLSessionDownloadTasks is whats making the app freeze and I don't know why :)

Comment: Where do you host your documents? Do you have a specific link to download them from? Because then you could try to download them in a more lightweight way.

Comment: I will edit my answer and add a second thing for you to consider.

Comment: Thanks Julian but that is not the problem :) download and run the code example I provided, inside the code example you will find the function I posted. Test it and tell me what you think.

Comment: Sorry, here it is: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2857188/BGTransferDemo.zip

Comment: Yeah. I got that error: The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: Okay I see. The app is downloading the stuff on the main thread, what then leads to slowing down.